# Sqoop Workflow with Oozie Always Fails

Tags: sqoop, hadoop2, oozie, cloudera-cdh, oozie-workflow

In the process of learning Sqoop I execute a sqoop command to fetch all mysql database in Cloudera's DH, which returns all available databases correctly. The problem is if I run the same command as a job in an Oozie workflow it always fails.

## job.properties

```
nameNode=hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020
resourceManager=0.0.0.0:8032

oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/oozie/pig_demo
```

## workflow.xml

```
<workflow-app name="foo-wf" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2">
    <start to="sqoop-36c5"/>

    <action name="sqoop-36c5">
        <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${resourceManager}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <command>list-databases --m 1 
                 --connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306"
                 --username retail_dba
                 --password cloudera</command>
         </sqoop>
         <ok to="finish"/>
         <error to="errorHalt"/>
    </action>

    <kill name="errorHalt">
        <message>Input unavailable,error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
   <end name="finish"/>
</workflow-app>
```

The following is logs generated

```
2019-01-24 09:52:09,352 INFO [Thread-69] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobHistoryEventHandler: Moved tmp to done: hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/history/done_intermediate/cloudera/job_1548311302916_0001-1548312666604-cloudera-oozie%3Alauncher%3AT%3Dsqoop%3AW%3Dfoo%2Dwf%3AA%3Dsqoop%2D36c5%3AID%3D00-1548312729060-1-0-SUCCEEDED-root.cloudera-1548312703464.jhist_tmp to hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/history/done_intermediate/cloudera/job_1548311302916_0001-1548312666604-cloudera-oozie%3Alauncher%3AT%3Dsqoop%3AW%3Dfoo%2Dwf%3AA%3Dsqoop%2D36c5%3AID%3D00-1548312729060-1-0-SUCCEEDED-root.cloudera-1548312703464.jhist
2019-01-24 09:52:09,352 INFO [Thread-69] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobHistoryEventHandler: Stopped JobHistoryEventHandler. super.stop()
2019-01-24 09:52:09,353 INFO [Thread-69] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl: KILLING attempt_1548311302916_0001_m_000000_0
2019-01-24 09:52:09,437 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl: attempt_1548311302916_0001_m_000000_0 TaskAttempt Transitioned from SUCCESS_FINISHING_CONTAINER to SUCCEEDED
2019-01-24 09:52:09,441 INFO [Thread-69] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Setting job diagnostics to 
2019-01-24 09:52:09,442 INFO [Thread-69] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: History url is http://quickstart.cloudera:19888/jobhistory/job/job_1548311302916_0001
2019-01-24 09:52:09,480 INFO [Thread-69] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Waiting for application to be successfully unregistered.
2019-01-24 09:52:10,483 INFO [Thread-69] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Final Stats: PendingReds:0 ScheduledMaps:0 ScheduledReds:0 AssignedMaps:1 AssignedReds:0 CompletedMaps:1 CompletedReds:0 ContAlloc:1 ContRel:0 HostLocal:0 RackLocal:0
2019-01-24 09:52:10,488 INFO [Thread-69] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Deleting staging directory hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020 /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/cloudera/.staging/job_1548311302916_0001
2019-01-24 09:52:10,505 INFO [Thread-69] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping server on 34049
2019-01-24 09:52:10,517 INFO [IPC Server listener on 34049] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server listener on 34049
2019-01-24 09:52:10,523 INFO [IPC Server Responder] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server Responder
2019-01-24 09:52:10,524 INFO [TaskHeartbeatHandler PingChecker] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.TaskHeartbeatHandler: TaskHeartbeatHandler thread interrupted
2019-01-24 09:52:10,531 INFO [Ping Checker] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.AbstractLivelinessMonitor: TaskAttemptFinishingMonitor thread interrupted
2019-01-24 09:52:10,556 INFO [Thread-69] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Job end notification started for jobID : job_1548311302916_0001
2019-01-24 09:52:10,560 INFO [Thread-69] org.mortbay.log: Job end notification attempts left 0
2019-01-24 09:52:10,560 INFO [Thread-69] org.mortbay.log: Job end notification trying http://quickstart.cloudera:11000/oozie/callback?id=0000000-190124093049946-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-36c5&status=SUCCEEDED
2019-01-24 09:52:10,590 INFO [Thread-69] org.mortbay.log: Job end notification to http://quickstart.cloudera:11000/oozie/callback?id=0000000-190124093049946-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-36c5&status=SUCCEEDED succeeded
2019-01-24 09:52:10,590 INFO [Thread-69] org.mortbay.log: Job end notification succeeded for job_1548311302916_0001
2019-01-24 09:52:15,605 INFO [Thread-69] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping server on 44688
2019-01-24 09:52:15,613 INFO [IPC Server Responder] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server Responder
2019-01-24 09:52:15,617 INFO [IPC Server listener on 44688] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server listener on 44688
2019-01-24 09:52:15,637 INFO [Thread-69] org.mortbay.log: Stopped HttpServer2$SelectChannelConnectorWithSafeStartup@0.0.0.0:0
```

The sqoop job succeeds but TaskAttempt Transitioned from SUCCESS_FINISHING_CONTAINER to SUCCEEDED is KILLED, why is that.

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ yarn version
Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.13.0
Subversion http://github.com/cloudera/hadoop -r 42e8860b182e55321bd5f5605264da4adc8882be
Compiled by jenkins on 2017-10-04T18:08Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 5e84c185f8a22158e2b0e4b8f85311
This command was run using /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common-2.6.0-cdh5.13.0.jar
```

Comment: The most obvious hack here is to increase the memory allocation and any CPU allocation to your quickstart VM. As in resize your VM and try running the job again.

2019-01-24 09:52:09,353 INFO [Thread-69] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl: KILLING attempt_1548311302916_0001_m_000000_0

Comment: @RaunakJhawar, i have allocated 8192MB base memory, 2CPUs processors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are running a listing database command. Not sure why you have put that in workflow.xml file.

I have experienced the Cloudera VM does not behave very consistently as we generally run it with limited memory and either container is not allocated or it is killed. Restarting the entire VM does not help also.

If you get a fresh instance of Cloudera VM again with the image and try to run it, it may solve your problem. It worked for us in past.